# How to keep custom properties between IntelliJ Idea updates?

Tags: intellij-idea, i3

I use a custom property in IntelliJ Idea to make it work with i3wm (it looses focus when changing workspaces):

`suppress.focus.stealing=false`

Each time I update IntelliJ, I have to add it again to /idea/bin/idea.properties which it's a bit tedious.

Is it possible to keep it between updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Help | Edit Custom Properties... action to create an idea.properties file in your config directory. This property file will be preserved between updates.

Comment: How is this different of edit idea/bin/idea.properties and add the configuration directly in the file?

Comment: The difference is that you'll be adding properties to a file which is not overwritten when IntelliJ IDEA is upgraded. IntelliJ IDEA reads the properties from a file in the config directory if it exists, and if it doesn't, the file in the distribution is used.

Comment: After update to 2020.3, I can confirm it works. Thanks